# How do I find the current user's own email address, using Exchange Web Services?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using UseDefaultCredentials = true to authenticate to EWS. It works fine for sending and receiving, but I now need to find out the email address of the current user, but I can't see any obvious way of doing this in the API.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is just to be use ConvertId with generic email address (Mailbox@domain.com always work for me) eg if you use

```
        Folder Inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        AlternateId aiAlternateid = new AlternateId(IdFormat.EwsId, Inbox.Id.UniqueId, "mailbox@domain.com");
        AlternateIdBase aiResponse = service.ConvertId(aiAlternateid, IdFormat.EwsId);
        Console.WriteLine(((AlternateId)aiResponse).Mailbox);
```

EWS should return the correct SMTPAddress of the Mailbox in the Mailbox property returned by this operation.

Cheers
Glen